# ZF2: run MySQL command "SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1" before executing SQL-statements

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

How do I execute a query (e.g. `SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1`) before running statements in ZF2 (Zend Framework 2)?

I tried already setting it in the "driver_options" but with no success.

Usually many statements will be build with \Zend\Paginator\Adapter\DbTableGateway or \Zend\Paginator\Adapter\DbSelect.

I think there should be a hook via the "Shared Manager", but dont know how to implement it.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Pull your adapter instance from the service manager and [use the `query` method](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.db.adapter.html#query-execution-through-zend-db-adapter-adapter-query) to execute it.  Alternatively, if the underlying adapter natively supports it you can pass options at the time you configure the adapter.  There's an example of doing that in [the manual comments section, here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.db.adapter.html#comment-1499522511) for a different option (forcing UTF8)

Comment: `'db' => array('driver_options' => array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET SESSION SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1'))` I've already tried with no success as described

Comment: Ah, then the first thing I mentioned (`query`) might be your only option.  If you have access to your database server configuration you could also configure it there.